# How can I get the cell contents including a linebreak within the cell?

Tags: vba, excel, cells

I'm trying to get the string value of a cell that is having a line break inside, using the ".Value" function.

Referring to cells B6 and B7 below:

[image]

Syntax I'm using:

```
Dim foo as String
foo = Range("B6").Value
```

Both B6 and B7 returns as a single line string e.g. "Dear Anon,Kindly grant..." while I need to have the actual value including the line breaks.

Is there a straight-forward way to accomplish what I need?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

I'm actually building the strings into an html content so I can send it via email. With this, I'm guessing I would need to check whether the cell is having line breaks and replace each line break with the html tag "**`< br >`**" - **without actually replacing the cell contents.**

e.g. I need value taken from cell B6 to transform into something like:

`<br>"Dear Anon,< br >< br >Kindly grant the corre....."`

Hope you can help..

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is... A line break is a character like any other (number 13 in the ASCII list), it should be stored on a string variable... However, write `foo = Range("B6").Text` instead of `foo = Range("B6").Value`.

Comment: @pnuts I'm considering this as a final resort. I'm looking for a way to do it without getting the content from 2 different cells..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the actual value, including the line breaks, use the code you currently have, i.e.

```
Dim foo as String
foo = Range("B6").Value
```

If you include a statement such as `MsgBox foo`, or `Debug.Print foo`, after those statements you will see that the line breaks are included in the string.

---

Based on your updated question, try using

```
Dim foo As String
foo = Replace(Range("B6").Value, vbLf, "<br>")
```

That will remove the line feed characters and insert the string `"<br>"` into their place.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Sorry but I just edited the question a few moments ago. I suddenly realized that I would need html breaks to replace the line breaks..

Comment: @iamkenos Saw the edit as soon as I finished the answer, so have updated the answer.

Comment: Plain and simple. Exactly what I needed. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

This will replace all newline feed with < br >

```
  Dim str As String
  str = Range("B6").Value
  str = Replace(str, Chr(10), "<br>")
```